# Vertical center inside columns in bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap, I am working on a simple project. What I need is that I need my heading inside `col-md-6` to be vertically centered.

Here is my Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid main_container">
    <div class="row inside_main_container">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 homepage_container pink darken-1">
            <h1> i lost something </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 homepage_container deep-purple darken-1">
            <h1> i found something </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 homepage_container teal darken-1">
            <h1> show me what's lost </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 homepage_container light-blue darken-1">
            <h1> show me what's found </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -60px 0 -40px;
    padding: 60px 0 40px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inside_main_container {
    margin: 0 !important;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
.homepage_container {
    width:100%;
    height: 50% !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.homepage_container h1 { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I have tried `.flex-md-middle,` `.align-middle` , `.vertical-center` , `.align-self-center` BUT nothing is working.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Approaches from the other questions seem to work https://www.codeply.com/go/Q3bz4CVtP5

Comment: its vertical and working fine, but when i used `text-align:center` it didnt goes to horizontally center ?

Comment: Use the `justify-content-center` class

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working perfectly :)